# Acentuação em meta description

Tags: seo

Ao utilizarmos prática [SEO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_para_motores_de_busca) em nosso site, temos que adicionar a `<meta name="description">` para ser melhor apresentado, dentre outras coisas.
Minha dúvida está em utilizar ou acentuação na descrição.

- Existe alguma desvantagem?
- Se quisermos ampliar as busca para outros idiomas, acentos podem ser prejudiciais?
- Em questão de posicionamento nas buscas, acentuação pode melhorar ou atrapalhar?

Comment: Caracteres especiais podem ser criados usando Unicode, isso já ouvi dizer que é mais vantajoso.

Comment: @durtto Eu também li isso, mas não acho nada concreto com fontes e demais informações.

Comment: Veja esse link. Tem fundamentação. http://www.aukseo.co.uk/a-guide-to-special-character-use-in-title-tags-1180/

Comment: @durtto Vou ler ele, obrigado.

Comment: Esse também é muito bom... http://antezeta.com/news/accented-characters

Comment: Eu queria poder te ajudar, mas não tenho esse conhecimento, o que posso fazer é pesquisar fontes o mais confiáveis possíveis e tentar elaborar uma resposta baseada. Vou tentar de hoje para amanhã. Sua pergunta é muito boa, pois tem que ser uma resposta baseada em testes realizados.

Comment: @durtto Essa foi um dúvida que tive, mas estou realizando testes para verificar isso também. Mas como eu disse, queria algo para me embasar (alguma referência concreta).

Answer (score 1):

Creio que seja melhor usar os acentos, imagine um usuário brasileiro pesquisando pelo seu site no Google e vendo uma descrição com palavras escritas de forma errada...

Se vai ampliar as buscas em outros idiomas, a descrição terá que ser traduzida para o idioma certo? Caso contrário que sentido faria exibir uma descrição em português e ainda sem acentos para um alemão? rs

Espero ter ajudado, e me desculpe se interpretei mal a sua pergunta.

Comment: A questão de outro idioma foi mais em questão de uma pessoa leiga pesquisar, por exemplo: Eu pesquiso sempre em inglês, mas não uso `'`, como em **It's**, e sim **it is**. Minha dúvida é parecida, só que em português. Uma pessoa vir pesquisar, ela digita **você** ou **voce**? Mas a dúvida mesmo é como os acentos são interpretados  em questão de posicionamento.

Comment: Entendi, teria que pesquisar mais, mas creio que a acentuação não tenha influência nisso. O plugin YoastSEO que utilizo no Wordpress por exemplo nas versões mais antigas dava uma classificação baixa caso a palavra-chave informada tivesse com acento em alguns lugares e sem acento em outros, já nas versões mais atualizadas ele reconhece a palavra como sendo igual, independente de ter ou não acento. Apenas uma suposição.

Comment: Então, no caso é um plugin. O que ele faz por trás não tem como saber (eu acho, não seu se é Open Source). As vezes ele mesmo retira os acentos, as vezes os mecanismos ficaram "mais inteligentes".